# Python - Write a list of tuples to a CSV file ignoring the commas within parentheses

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

So I have the following list:
    L2 = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5)]

I want to write it to a csv file in one column and four rows:

```
(1,2)
(1,3)
(1,4)
(1,5)
```

However my wonderful attempt here

```
with open('myfile.csv', "w") as outfile:
    for entries in L2:
        outfile.write(str(entries))
        outfile.write("\n")
```

Leads me to two columns and four rows:

```
(1   2)
(1   3)
(1   4)
(1   5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop over the items and use string formatting:

```
with open('myfile.csv', "w") as outfile:
   for a, b in L2:
      outfile.write("({},{})\n".format(a, b))
```

Comment: You mean outfile.write("({},{})\n".format(a, b)) or outfile.write("({},{})\n").format(a, b)?

Comment: @user3400351 thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: It doesn't work :( I get the same 2 columns and 4 rows

Answer (score 0):

Try making them strings first.

```
L2 = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5)]
L2 = [str(x) for x in L2]
```

Comment: The program won't even compile, invalid syntax on the for word

Comment: @user3400351 I literally just copied and pasted into Ipython and it worked fine